# Mysql_fetch_assoc is losing fields after assigning it to a array variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple function that calls a select query and populates an array with the results:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

for ($n=0; $n < mysql_num_rows($result); $n++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $output[$n] = $row;
}

return $output;
```

My table has about 60+ fields and `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns all of them.  However when assigning a row of data to the `$output` array, I lose more than half of the fields.

Comment: tbh I don't believe you :P  I think there's something else going on

Comment: so if you do $output[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); you get all the fields youre expecting?

Also can we see the query?

Comment: my problem is the number of fields returned, not rows.  I get all rows just fine.  When I try $output[$n] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result), my debugger says the value is : evaluating...

Here is the query:

SELECT * FROM customer a, child b
where a.customer_id = b.parent_id and a.customer_id = 1 and b.isdelete=0

Comment: $row gives me all the fields from my tables for $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: could it be that netbeans is not showing me all of my fields?  the result is surely not showing on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my own question :-\

This code works just fine and all fields are delivered.  No problem with PHP or Mysql.

Apparently, netbeans has some limitation on displaying all fields when viewing an array variable.  However, when specifically using a watch variable, it will display the value.

Don't know how to increase the number of fields in the netbeans IDE during debug.